# setVisibility(View.GONE) not working on onCreate

Tags: java, android

I have an activity where in I have hide to some fields depending on the value of some field, the problem is setVisibility(View.GONE) is not working.

```
         if(String.valueOf(householdMember.getCol11WithWork()).equals("2")){
                Spinner c = findViewById(R.id.col11a_answer);
                c.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }
```

Here's my code. Any idea why does the setVisibility does not work?

Comment: you are sure taht getCol11WithWork() is equal with 2?

Comment: There's no way for anyone else to verify that that `setVisibility` ever gets called based on the information you've provided.

Comment: I just have to ask: is `setVisibility` called at all?

Comment: @АлександрВолошиновский yes. I tried logging the value inside the if statement